# Running MalwareBytes & Spybot without Defender stepping aside

Tags: anti-virus

For years, I had Microsoft Security Essential on Windows 7, and I installed MalwareBytes and Spybot Search & Destroy.  I deactivated real time components of the non-native antimalware products.  On the odd occassion in which I needed to execute a downloaded file (e.g., to install something), I would update all 3 databases and scan the file.

I just bought a Windows 10 computer because Windows 7 is no longer supported.  I want the native Windows Defender to be the main antimalware.  Web searching confirms that I should de-activate real time components of non-native antimalware.  But it also reveals that Defender steps aside if another antimalware program is detected.

**Does that mean it is not sufficient to simply turn off non-native real time components?**

**How would I make Defender to be the main antimalware, with MalwareBytes and Spybot only for on-demand scans of selected files or file trees?**

Comment: Spybot S&D... I'd forgotten all about that wonderful application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Malwarebytes, it is possible to run it side-by-side with Windows Defender, and have it be the "main" Antivirus on the system. See this thread here:

https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/253972-malwarebytes-4-faqs/?tab=comments#comment-1346719

So basically what you want do here is go in Malwarebytes Settings (gear icon in the top right corner), go to the Security tab, scroll down, and disable the option under Windows Security Center (to register Malwarebytes there). That will leave Malwarebytes real-time monitoring enabled, but also allow Windows Defender's real-time monitoring to be enabled.

As for Spybot S&D, see their support article regarding that situation.

https://www.safer-networking.org/pt-br/faq/spybot-defender-windows-10/

One thing to note is that for both of these programs, the real-time monitoring comes only with their paid version. So if you don't want to use their real-time monitoring capabilities, and run scans manually, you should just use their free version.

Comment: Hmm.  That's what I'm doing.  But I want to donate at some point, without activating the real-time components.  I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.  In my original question, however, I may have left some confusion. I don't want the real-time of 3rd party antimalware to operate. I simply want Defender to be the main antimalware for all things (rather than stepping aside), with the 3rd party antimalware available for on-demand scanning of selected files. Would I be right in assuming that this is already the case for the free versions of MalwareBytes & Spybot?

Comment: It is already the case of for the free versions of Malwarebytes and Spybot, yes.

Comment: Thanks, Aura, for the confirmation.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!